# Xml communication problem. Cant save data to XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to save some data in XML with no success.

I implemented these functions that are necessary for all function inside the HTML. I can only read data but can't add, edit, delete them. In the picture, is the debug that shows the errors. In the other picture are some suggestions from the documentation. I have tried them but didn't success. Any suggestion? What did i do wrong?

```
  <div class="Border">
     <div class="Main" style="width:100%;height:600px;">
        <bdo Layout_Url="FirstDef.xml" Data_Url="FirstData.xml"
          Debug='problem'
          Upload_Url="FirstData.xml" Upload_Data="Data" Upload_Type="1" Upload_XML="1" Upload_Param_Do="Save"
             ></bdo>
         ></bdo>
     </div>
  </div>
```

[Debug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q73JU.png)
[Documentation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6hfU.png)

Comment: You are referring to `xml`. Xml is a standardized syntax to represent semi-structured data with a host of other standard that specialize the syntax and define semantics. You seem to be operating in a particular application environment that uses a xml-based control methodology. It is unlikely that you receive much help without naming that environment. What application / docs do your screenshots show? What do you want to accomplish ? What have you tried ? What are the stumbling blocks encountered ?